# Julia on Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, julia

I am trying to install Julia into a Windows 7 machine from source via Cygwin.

I've been following the instructions on here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/README.windows.md

I was able to download cygwin and all the necessary packages by pasting this code:

```
setup-x86_64.exe -s <url> -q -P cmake,gcc-g++,git,make,patch,curl,m4,python,p7zip,mingw64-i686-gcc-g++,mingw64-i686-gcc-fortran,mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++,mingw64-x86_64-gcc-fortran
:: replace <url> with a site from https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html
:: or run setup manually first and select a mirror
```

Then I restarted cygwin to my home directory (/home/{computer name}).

I built Julia from source using the following code:

```
git clone https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
cd julia
echo 'XC_HOST = x86_64-w64-mingw32' > Make.user   # for 64 bit Julia
make -j 4
```

which took like 2 hours but it was built successfully, at least it seemed to be.

However, I could not complete the next step, which is to simply run julia that should be at `usr/bin/julia.exe`

This wasn't present either at `/usr/bin` or `/home/{computer name}/julia/usr/bin`.

I would appreciate help in figuring out how to find the executable, or any mistakes I may have made in the prior steps.

Comment: did you run `make install`?

Comment: @Gnimuc i did not, so i tried it. Unfortunately some error came up at `[ 78%] Linking CXX shared library ../../bin/LLVM.dll` saying `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` and `make[5]: *** [tools/llvm-shlib/CMakeFiles/LLVM.dir/build.make:213: bin/LLVM.dll] Error 1`

Comment: it looks like the build is not fully successful

Comment: i'll retry the build and if i see any errors i'll close this question and post a new one (if no duplicate)

Comment: if the error is reproducible, you might need to file an issue on Github.

Comment: Add verbosity to the build to see the full compiler invocation and the complete error message

Comment: I got error during a simple `make -d`. I posted to github as issue #29488 (https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/29488). The error message is little long but I added it to the issue page.